# Error starting Spring Boot: Failed to start bean 'subProtocolWebSocketHandler'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No handlers

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-websocket

I am working on a Spring Boot application implementing a web socket and I am finding the following problem.

So first of all I have this **WebSocketConfig** class implementing **WebSocketConfigurer**:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer {
//public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addHandler(new SocketTextHandler(), "/deposit-notification");
    }

}
```

As you can see here I am registering the handler with the related endpoint.

Then I have this **SocketTextHandler** classi implementing the **TextWebSocketHandler** interface that implements the web socket logic:

```
@Component
public class SocketTextHandler extends TextWebSocketHandler {

    @Override
    public void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session, TextMessage message)
            throws InterruptedException, IOException {

        String payload = message.getPayload();
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(payload);
        session.sendMessage(new TextMessage("Hi " + jsonObject.get("user") + " how may we help you?"));
    }

}
```

I also have this **SocketSecurityConfig** extending **AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer** in order to have a minimal security configuration on this endpoint (enabling connection only from authenticated users):

```
public class SocketSecurityConfig extends AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    
    @Override 
    protected void configureInbound(MessageSecurityMetadataSourceRegistry messages) { 
        messages
          .simpDestMatchers("/deposit-notification").authenticated()
          .anyMessage().authenticated(); 
    }

}
```

The problem is that now running my application I obtain this error message in the STS stacktrace:

```
2022-02-18 16:59:56.451[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m28324[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.boot.SpringApplication              [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'subProtocolWebSocketHandler'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No handlers
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:181) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:170) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:356) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:155) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:123) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:935) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:586) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at com.easydefi.users.GetUserWsApplication.main(GetUserWsApplication.java:15) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No handlers
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:121) ~[spring-core-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.SubProtocolWebSocketHandler.start(SubProtocolWebSocketHandler.java:270) ~[spring-websocket-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:178) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
```

Why? What is wrong? What am I missing? How can I try to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error , solved by implement
`WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer` instead of `AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer`

```java
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
    public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer   {

        //AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer 


        @Override
        public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
            config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
            config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
        }


        @Override
        public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
            registry.addEndpoint("/ws").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS(); 
        }


    }
```

Comment: I have the same configuration, but I get OP's error when i add "@component" to the handler but when i declare a bean in config class it works fine. I need to autowire stuff in the handler so I need to add "@component" but it does not seem to work.